# What is the average amount of gates needed to implement a random Clifford gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, clifford-group, random-quantum-circuit

Given a Clifford gate acting on $n$ qubits is implemented using its [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_gates#Generators_of_the_Clifford_group), what is the average number of gates needed to implement a random Clifford gate as a function of $n$?

Answer (score 2):

It's $O(n^2)$ operations from various constructive decompositions (such as in ["Hadamard-free circuits expose the structure of the Clifford group
"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09412)).

You can prove from information theoretic bounds that there has to be at least $\Omega(n^2/ \lg n)$ gates in the worst case, because otherwise there wouldn't be enough distinct possible circuits to give a different one to each different operation. And the majority of the circuits have to be this large or else again they won't fit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Craig, I really appreciate it. Can you please provide a reference for your second point: "You can prove from information theoretic bounds that there has to be at least $\Omega(n^2/ \lg n)$ gates in the worst case... And the majority of the circuits have to be this large or else again they won't fit" ?

Comment: Also, I am a bit confused as to how your two points don't contradict each other... At first you say it is $O(n^2)$, but then say it is $\Omega(n^2/ \lg n)$. That means the lower bound is higher than the upper bound.

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 I don't have a reference, it's just based on the size of the Clifford group for $n$ qubits and how many different $n$-qubit circuits you can make with $m$ gates. I don't know what you're talking about with the lower bound being higher than the upper bound. n^2/lg n is less than n^2.

Comment: oh true. for some reason I was reading the division as multiplication...! just getting over a bout of COVID rn. Seems I still have a bit of brain fog.

Comment: I would've written your answer as "there has to be at least $\Omega(n^2/ \lg n)$ gates in the *best* case" instead of "there has to be at least $\Omega(n^2/ \lg n)$ gates in the *worst* case"

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 When I said "in worst case" I meant "for the hardest circuit to make". The worst case complexity as opposed to the expected case complexity (though they happen to be the same for this kind of problem).